# Apple acceptance on custom reachability class?

Tags: ios, reachability

I Looking to upload my app with Reachability class, in which I have changed reachability class name to UploadReachability,please let me know if anyone has experience with Apple about reachability. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: changing the name doesn't matter

Comment: thanks  Vivek Sehrawat for reply, are you sure ?

Comment: "Reachablity" is just a class name it. you can change its name to"XYZ".Nothing related to apple acceptance to class name

Comment: hey , why are you changing the name of the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the `Reachability` class itself. Just check one of the class files for the license which gives you permission to modify and distribute the code. You can refer the same here.

> File: Reachability.h
>
> Abstract: Basic demonstration of how to use the SystemConfiguration Reachablity APIs.
>     Version: 3.0
>
> Disclaimer: IMPORTANT:  This Apple software is supplied to you by Apple
>    Inc. ("Apple") in consideration of your agreement to the following
>    terms, and your use, installation, modification or redistribution of
>    this Apple software constitutes acceptance of these terms.  If you do
>    not agree with these terms, please do not use, install, modify or
>    redistribute this Apple software.
>
> In consideration of your agreement to abide by the following terms, and
>    subject to these terms, Apple grants you a personal, non-exclusive
>    license, under Apple's copyrights in this original Apple software (the
>    "Apple Software"), to use, reproduce, modify and redistribute the Apple
>    Software, with or without modifications, in source and/or binary forms;
>    provided that if you redistribute the Apple Software in its entirety and
>    without modifications, you must retain this notice and the following
>    text and disclaimers in all such redistributions of the Apple Software.
>    Neither the name, trademarks, service marks or logos of Apple Inc. may
>    be used to endorse or promote products derived from the Apple Software
>    without specific prior written permission from Apple.  Except as
>    expressly stated in this notice, no other rights or licenses, express or
>    implied, are granted by Apple herein, including but not limited to any
>    patent rights that may be infringed by your derivative works or by other
>    works in which the Apple Software may be incorporated.
>
> The Apple Software is provided by Apple on an "AS IS" basis.  APPLE
>    MAKES NO WARRANTIES, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING WITHOUT LIMITATION
>    THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF NON-INFRINGEMENT, MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS
>    FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE, REGARDING THE APPLE SOFTWARE OR ITS USE AND
>    OPERATION ALONE OR IN COMBINATION WITH YOUR PRODUCTS.
>
> IN NO EVENT SHALL APPLE BE LIABLE FOR ANY SPECIAL, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL
>    OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF
>    SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS
>    INTERRUPTION) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE, REPRODUCTION,
>    MODIFICATION AND/OR DISTRIBUTION OF THE APPLE SOFTWARE, HOWEVER CAUSED
>    AND WHETHER UNDER THEORY OF CONTRACT, TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE),
>    STRICT LIABILITY OR OTHERWISE, EVEN IF APPLE HAS BEEN ADVISED OF THE
>    POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
>
> Copyright (C) 2013 Apple Inc. All Rights Reserved.

So you can go ahead and modify the code as long as you follow Apple's T&C.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Amar for answer,Actually I am looking to change Reachability class name not to modify Class API's.

Comment: @SandeepKhade Should be okay.

Comment: it's okay I will respond you if I get any trouble,Thanks for you r support !

Comment: Actually he is asking change Reachability class name not to modify Class API's

Comment: @kagmanoj I think you should read above comments before making invalid remarks.

Comment: @kagmanoj you are right !

Answer (score 0):

Even if you write your own new reachability class from scratch with anyname Apple Policies will not bother you.. untill you are trying to do some nasty things or using some private APIS you are App store safe..